# Why is this not context free grammar?

Tags: math

I vaguely recall { a^n b^n c^n is, n>=0 } not context free.

But isn't the following a valid context free grammar that captures the above

S -> abcS
S -> null

Quoting Wikipedia:

> "In formal language theory, a context-free grammar (CFG) is a formal grammar in which every production rule is of the form
>   V → w
>   where V is a single nonterminal symbol, and w is a string of terminals and/or nonterminals (w can be empty)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case you are wondering why it's not a context free grammar, here's a quick explanation:

A context free grammar is a grammar that can be recognized by a push-down automaton, which is a finite state automaton with the addition of a stack.

An example of a CFG is a^n b^n.  If you think about it, we can push a token on our stack for every 'a' that we see and pop a token off the stack for every 'b' we see.  We will fail at any point if we
- push a token after popping (a 'b' followed by an 'a')
- finish processing the string but we still have tokens on the stack (more 'a's than 'b's)
- try to pop an empty stack (more 'b's than 'a's)

If you think about how to recognize a^n b^n c^n with a push-down automaton, you will probably realize that is impossible after some playing around.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

S -> abcS produces something like that (abc)^n not a^n b^n c^n

Answer (score 2):

You've written a production rule that generates abc^n, not a^n b^n c^n.

Answer (score 2):

For n=2 shouldn't the production be: aabbcc?  But wouldn't your example grammar produce abcabc?