# Why is this not CFG?

Tags: context-free-grammar, automata, pushdown-automaton

Though this is a repitition of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615112/why-is-this-not-context-free-grammer), I talking in terms of designing a PDA.

Now, I know I'm wrong, because this is a well publicised example, but where did I go wrong in the PDA design below?

I want to accept language `{a^n b^n c^n: n>=0}`

I push two `1`'s on the stack every time I encounter an `a`, pop one for `b` and pop one for `c` and check if I have an empty stack.
I defined the transition functions (minimal) as:

`(q0, a, Z) = (q0, 11Z)`
`(q0, a, 1) = (q0, 111)`
`(q0, b, 1) = (q1, delta)`
`(q1, c, 1) = (q2, delta)`
`(q2, delta, Z) = (q-Final, Z) (epsilon move)`

`Z is empty stack`

Doesn't this PDA accept such a language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PDA accepts the language:

```
{a^n b^i c^j; n >= 0 and i + j = 2n}
```

Which is not the same as `{a^n b^n c^n: n>=0}`, a subset of the above language, specifically when `i = n` and `j = n`.